# How to get an id of element to which I drag a "draggable" element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

So I have divs like this on my page:

```
<div class="drag"></div>
```

And this jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.drag').draggable();

});    //-->
</script>
```

The draggable effect works well.

But I would like to find out an id of a HTML tag where the draggable div gets dropped. If it has any.

So if I drag the div to a table with id="my-table", I want to get that value inside js and do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a draggable you also have a droppable...correct?

so you could do something like this:

```
$("#draggable").draggable();
$("#droppable").droppable({
  drop: function() {
    alert('dropped');
    var dropId = $(this).attr('id');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed this post because I recently posted a very similar question, so I will just leave the link here in case anyone wants tot take a look.

[How to find out about the "snapped to" element for jQuery UI draggable elements on snap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177867/how-to-find-out-about-the-snapped-to-element-for-jquery-ui-draggable-elements-o/5181159#5181159)