# How to find out about the "snapped to" element for jQuery UI draggable elements on snap

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm working a few draggable elements that should be snapping to other elements, which all have classes, something like, `".classes"` and also a unique id, `"#class_id"`. Once the draggable elements are done being dragged, I would like to find out which of those ".classes" that the draggable element has snapped to.

I suppose I could compute the closest element based on the current position of the dragged element, but I feel there should be an easier way than brute force, since `jQuery` would have to keep some sort of variable to make sure the snapping works.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

jQueryUI *does* keep an internal "state" of "snapped" elements, but you have to work a little to get at it.

You're going to want to define an event handler for the [`stop`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-stop) event (which is called when a draggable object is stopped dragging).

An array called `snapElements` is maintained inside the widget data, and it looks something like this:

```
[ 
    { 
        height: 102, 
        item: { /* DOM element */ }, 
        left: 10, 
        snapping: false, 
        top: 10, 
        width: 102 
    }, ...
]
```

What we really care about here is the `item` and `snapping` properties. `snapping` will tell us if the item is currently "snapping" to a draggable object.

With this array in mind, we can write code like this to determine the snappable targets that are currently "snapping":

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    snap: ".snap",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        /* Get the possible snap targets: */
        var snapped = $(this).data('draggable').snapElements;

        /* Pull out only the snap targets that are "snapping": */
        var snappedTo = $.map(snapped, function(element) {
            return element.snapping ? element.item : null;
        });

        /* Process the results in the snappedTo array! */
    }
});
```

The reason that your end result is an array and not a single DOM element is that jQueryUI is actually smart enough to realize when you've snapped a `draggable` to two "snappable" elements.

Here's a working example that shows all of this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/uYpnW/5/

Hope that helps.

Comment: @jet: Awesome, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: HiThis helped me with a problem along the same lines. Thanks

Comment: this helps me also but has a problem: snapElements is populated only after the first drag, if I create a draggable exactely over the snap to element without moving it snapElements  will be emoty

Comment: Note that in jQuery UI 1.9 and above, `$(this).data('draggable')` becomes `$(this).data('ui-draggable')` due to changed naming conventions.

Comment: I ended up using $(this).data('ui-draggable').element.parent() because I used clone. Also I didn't use appendTo property. To get the element you came from use $(this).data('ui-draggable').helper.parent()

Comment: Having an issue with this where sometimes jQuery will select two snap-point element as `snapping` = true. Pretty unreliable.

Maybe my implementation is slightly different, and this may not be happening to others. Let me know below - thanks.