# jQuery UI – draggable 'snap' event

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm looking a way to binding the `snap` event.

When I'm dragging an element over my surface and the *draggable* element is *snapped* to a declared snap position I want to trigger an event.

Something like this:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
  snap: ".grid",
  snaped: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Bonus point: with a reference to the `.grid` element where the *draggable* element was *snapped*.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `draggable` widget does not expose such an event out of the box (yet). You could modify it and maintain your custom version or, better, derive a new widget from it and implement the new event there. There is, however, a third way.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5177867/464709), we know the widget stores an array of the potentially "snappable" elements in its `snapElements` property. In turn, each element in this array exposes a `snapping` property that is `true` if the draggable helper is currently snapped to this element and `false` otherwise (the helper can snap to several elements at the same time).

The `snapElements` array is updated for every `drag` event, so it is always up-to-date in `drag` handlers. From there, we only have to obtain the `draggable` widget instance from the associated element with [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), and call its `_trigger()` method to raise our own `snapped` event (actually `dragsnapped` under the hood). In passing, we can [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) the `ui` object with a jQuery object wrapping the snapped element:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var draggable = $(this).data("draggable");
        $.each(draggable.snapElements, function(index, element) {
            if (element.snapping) {
                draggable._trigger("snapped", event, $.extend({}, ui, {
                    snapElement: $(element.item)
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    snap: ".grid",
    snapped: function(event, ui) {
        // Do something with 'ui.snapElement'...
    }
});
```

The code above, however, can still be improved. As it stands, a `snapped` event will be triggered for every `drag` event (which occurs *a lot*) as long as the draggable helper remains snapped to an element. In addition, no event is triggered when snapping ends, which is not very practical, and detracts from the convention for such events to occur in pairs (`snapped-in`, `snapped-out`).

Luckily, the `snapElements` array is persistent, so we can use it to store state. We can add a `snappingKnown` property to each array element in order to track that we already have triggered a `snapped` event for that element. Moreover, we can use it to detect that an element has been snapped out since the last call and react accordingly.

Note that rather than introducing another `snapped-out` event, the code below chooses to pass an additional `snapping` property (reflecting the element's current state) in the `ui` object (which is, of course, only a matter of preference):

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var draggable = $(this).data("draggable");
        $.each(draggable.snapElements, function(index, element) {
            ui = $.extend({}, ui, {
                snapElement: $(element.item),
                snapping: element.snapping
            });
            if (element.snapping) {
                if (!element.snappingKnown) {
                    element.snappingKnown = true;
                    draggable._trigger("snapped", event, ui);
                }
            } else if (element.snappingKnown) {
                element.snappingKnown = false;
                draggable._trigger("snapped", event, ui);
            }
        });
    },
    snap: ".grid",
    snapped: function(event, ui) {
        // Do something with 'ui.snapElement' and 'ui.snapping'...
        var snapper  = ui.snapElement.attr("id"),snapperPos = ui.snapElement.position(),
            snappee  = ui.helper.attr("id"),     snappeePos = ui.helper.position(),
            snapping = ui.snapping;
        // ...
    }
});
```

You can test this solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fhamidi/PjmJe/1/).

In closing, another improvement might be to make the `snapped` event *cancelable*, as the `drag` event is. To achieve that, we would have to return `false` from our `drag` handler if one of the calls to `_trigger()` returns `false`. You may want to think twice before implementing this, though, as canceling a drag operation on snap-in or snap-out does not look like a very user-friendly feature in the general case.

***Update:*** From jQuery UI 1.9 onwards, [the `data()` key becomes the widget's fully qualified name, with dots replaced by dashes](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changed-naming-convention-for-data-keys). Accordingly, the code used above to obtain the widget instance becomes:

```
var draggable = $(this).data("ui-draggable");
```

Instead of:

```
var draggable = $(this).data("draggable");
```

Using the unqualified name is still supported in 1.9 but is deprecated, and support will be dropped in 1.10.

Comment: Would you be super kind and update your snapped with the id of the snapping and the snapped to element(s) - I use 1.9.1 but need to find out where the snapping is in relation to the snapped to - the contents will be different if it is above, below, left or right - but right now I only found the snapping object and its position()

Comment: @mplungjan, if I understand your comment correctly, that information is already there. The "snapping" element is available in `ui.helper`, and the "snapped to" element is `ui.snapElement` when `ui.snapping` is `true`.

Comment: [Here is the followup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588413/detecting-draggable-snapper-position-relative-to-snappee) - no takers yet :(

Comment: It should be noted that "$(this).data("draggable")" has been renamed to $(this).data("ui-draggable") in newer versions...

Comment: @Andrew, did you read my answer in its entirety, including the update at the end?

Comment: Is there a way to use this solution with grid snapping (ie. draggable({grid: [20,20]}))? I have tried to implement this but no events are fired in this case.

Comment: is there a method to use this code witch an if / else statement in the snapped function. something like if(element.snappingKnown == true).

Answer (score 1):

In jquery-ui 1.10.0, the above code doesn't work.  The drag function is instead:

```
drag: function(event, ui) {
  var draggable = $(this).data("ui-draggable")
  $.each(draggable.snapElements, function(index, element) {
    if(element.snapping) {
      draggable._trigger("snapped", event, $.extend({}, ui, {
        snapElement: $(element.item)
      }));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I understand my answer is a little long, but did you try reading it in its entirety? :)

Comment: The difference is that $(this).data('draggable') does not exist in 1.10+.  You must use 'ui-draggable' instead.  Instead of just posting the entire set of code he really should have just said that.