# 'snap' event in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery UI – draggable 'snap' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611765/jquery-ui-draggable-snap-event)

I'm looking a way to binding the snap event.

When I'm dragging an element over my surface and the draggable element is snapped to a declared snap position I want to trigger an event.

Something like this:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
  snap: ".grid",
  snaped: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Bonus point: with a reference to the .grid element where the draggable element was snapped.

Comment: This question was already asked please look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611765/jquery-ui-draggable-snap-event