# Jquery UI snapMode center

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I have built a cloze. Very long words are not easy to place in the gap. I do not want to expand the gap. So it's possible that the element jumps (snap) to the center of the gap if it is hover.

```
$('.gap').draggable({
    disabled: true,
    snap: '.ui-draggable',
    snapMode: 'inner', /* i find "inner", "outer", "both"*/
});
```

[here the example](http://jsfiddle.net/somaberlin/7rwWA/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this might not be quite what your looking for but one option is to just make the `.gap` as wide as the word your dragging.  This can be done really easily like so

http://jsfiddle.net/7rwWA/1/

Now I think it would be even better to only make the `.gap` wider when your hovering over it but there is no built in way to do this.  But its possible if you were to check for the `.gap` that a snap was triggered on and then make the gap bigger.  This question may be useful.

[Jquery UI – draggable 'snap' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611765/jquery-ui-draggable-snap-event)

Comment: @Obeck please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved. Thanks