# jQuery UI Draggable Snapping into a Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

### Description of Problem ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8yaz/3/)):

Using jQuery UI's `.draggable()` function, I'm trying to make the red element snap to the inside of the blue container. It's snapping first to one edge rather than completely inside it (i.e. to both edges). You must continue dragging it until it snaps to the other axis.

When it begins to snap at any angle, I want it to go to its final position (fully inside the container). Is there a way to detect when a snap begins (i.e. the event is fired) and then use that to manually reposition the red box?

### Example Code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#box').draggable({
    snap: '#container',
    snapMode: 'inner',
    snapTolerance: 50
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#box {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
#container {
    width: 102px;
    height: 102px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -51px;
    margin-left: -51px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: I am not really sure what are you asking, but have you tried increasing the snap tolerance?

Comment: Drag it near the blue box. It will snap to one edge first - either vertical or horizontal. When it begins to snap, I want it to immediately snap to both edges and end up at its final destination (the container). I don't know how to describe the problem better than that, unfortunately.

Comment: And yes, adjusting the tolerance just makes it snap to one edge from a greater distance.

Comment: Well, actually, it is not snapping to the outer edge, it is actually snapping to the same "level". You can see that if you move it about 1cm from the blue box (edges are not touching), you will see that both bottom edges remain in line. When I pull it slowly closer to the blue box it does not actually snap to the outer edge, at least in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W8yaz/9/

Snap event help: [Jquery UI – draggable 'snap' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611765/jquery-ui-draggable-snap-event)

Right now, after snapping there is no more draggin possible. This will be another headache.

Beside note: you can't trigger mouseup to cancel the drag event, this is causing a known javascript error, can be seen in a previous fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W8yaz/7/

JavaScript:

```
$('#box').draggable({
    snap: '#container',
    snapMode: 'inner',
    snapTolerance: 50,
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('snapped')) {
            var position = $('#container').position();

            $(this).css({
                top: position.top,
                left: position.left
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            var draggable = $(this).data("uiDraggable");
            $.each(draggable.snapElements, function (index, element) {
                if (element.snapping) {
                    draggable._trigger("snapped", event, $.extend({}, ui, {
                        snapElement: $(element.item)
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    },
    snapped: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass('snapped');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this. I actually went with what I believe to be a much more elegant and workable solution using ``.droppable()``, but I do truly appreciate your effort here. You are a champion, sir.

Comment: Appreciate your tribute!