# jQuery UI draggable snap to grid, select element being snapped to?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I am using jQuery UI's draggable and droppable
The draggable elements are being set to snap to elements with a specific class

When the element is dropped, how do I select the element that is was be snapped to?
I can't seem to find anything in the documnetation
Thanks

Comment: Could you set up a test case for that? For example on jsFiddle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out about the "snapped to" element for jQuery UI draggable elements on snap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177867/how-to-find-out-about-the-snapped-to-element-for-jquery-ui-draggable-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to catch the STOP event within the jQuery UI events list found here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events

Example:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { $(this).parent()//you got it from here }
});
```