# Jquery Draggable UI | Change image size when it is dragged into container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using the Jquery Draggable UI: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

I'm working on a project where I can drag four images into 4 different containers. What I want to do is change the size of the image to the size of the container that it is dropped into. The image should revert back to its original size when it is taken outside of the container.

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/W8yaz/546/

Here is my code as of right now:

**HTML**

```
<div class="bordered-boxes">
  <ul>
    <li class="squaredotted">
      <div style="width:205px; height: 205px; border: 1px dotted #eee;" class='snappable'>

      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="squaredotted">
      <div class="" style="width:175px; height: 175px; border: 1px dotted #eee;">

      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="squaredotted">
      <div class="" style="width:145px; height: 145px; border: 1px dotted #eee;">

      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="squaredotted">
      <div class="" style="width:110px; height: 110px; border: 1px dotted #eee;">

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="" style="position: absolute; text-align: left; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); left: 760px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px; opacity: .7; font-style: italic;">
    <p>Least
      <br />Important</p>
  </div>

  <div class="" style="position: absolute; text-align: left; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); left: -95px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px; opacity: .7; font-style: italic;">
    <p>Most
      <br />Important</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-wrapper animation">

  <ul>
    <li class="square">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card" id="incapacitation-icon">
          <div class="front">
            <img src="assets/icons/icon-incapacitation.svg" width="100%" />

            <div class="more-info">
              <img src="assets/icon-info.svg" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="back">
            <section>
              <h4>Incapacitation</h4>

              <p>Confining Dangerous People</p>
            </section>

            <div class="close-icon">
              x
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="square">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card" id="deterrence-icon">
          <div class="front">
            <img src="assets/icons/icon-deterrence.svg" width="100%" />

            <div class="more-info">
              <img src="assets/icon-info.svg" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="back">
            <section>
              <h4>Deterrence</h4>

              <p>Setting an Example</p>
            </section>

            <div class="close-icon">
              x
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="square">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card" id="rehabilitation-icon">
          <div class="front">
            <img src="assets/icons/icon-rehabilitation.svg" width="100%" />

            <div class="more-info">
              <img src="assets/icon-info.svg" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="back">
            <section>
              <h4>Rehabilitation</h4>

              <p>Breaking the Cycle of Crime</p>
            </section>

            <div class="close-icon">
              x
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li style="margin-right:0;" class="square">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card" id="retribution-icon">
          <div class="front">
            <img src="assets/icons/icon-retribution.svg" width="100%" />

            <div class="more-info">
              <img src="assets/icon-info.svg" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="back">
            <section>
              <h4>Retribution</h4>

              <p>An Eye for An Eye</p>
            </section>

            <div class="close-icon">
              x
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.card-wrapper li { 
  height: 203px;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.card-wrapper .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
    perspective:800px;
}

.card-wrapper .card div {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
    z-index:10;
}

.card-wrapper .card .front {
}

.card-wrapper .card .back {
  background: #8d797a;
    z-index:0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.card-wrapper .card .back h4{
    font-size: 20px;
    color:#4b3839;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.card-wrapper .card .back section {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:30px;
}

.card-wrapper .card .back p {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color:white;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.card-wrapper .card.flip .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
    z-index:0;
}

.card-wrapper .card.flip .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
    z-index:10;
}

.card-wrapper .more-info {
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 1.5em !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: -28px;
    right: -18px;
    height: 1.5em !important;
}

.card-wrapper .close-icon {
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 1.5em !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: -28px;
    right: -18px;
    height: 1.5em !important;
}

.card-wrapper .card .close-icon {
    display: none;
}

.card-wrapper .card.flip .more-info {
    display: none;
}

.card-wrapper .card.flip .close-icon {
    display: block;
}

.card-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.bottom-row {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 70px;
    margin: auto;
}

.bottom-row li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 20% !important;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 3% !important;
    height: 117px !important;
    position: relative;
}

.bottom-row .back {
    display: none;
}

.bottom-row .more-info {
    display: none;
}

.bottom-row .more-info2 {
    display: none;
}

.bordered-boxes {
    position: absolute;
    width: 75%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: none;
    top: 50%; 
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.bordered-boxes ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.bordered-boxes ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 4%;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.square').draggable({
    snap: '.squaredotted',
    snapMode: 'inner',
    snapTolerance: 25,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here:
[How to find out about the "snapped to" element for jQuery UI draggable elements on snap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177867/how-to-find-out-about-the-snapped-to-element-for-jquery-ui-draggable-elements)

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    snap: ".snap",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        /* Get the possible snap targets: */
        var snapped = $(this).data('draggable').snapElements;

        /* Pull out only the snap targets that are "snapping": */
        var snappedTo = $.map(snapped, function(element) {
            return element.snapping ? element.item : null;
        });

        /* Process the results in the snappedTo array! */
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! With the code above, it looks like the snapped image stays on the container and cannot be moved. I still am a little confused on how I would increase the image size to the size of the container using the code above. I updated the fiddle to show what I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/W8yaz/547/

Comment: I see some one has a better answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177867/how-to-find-out-about-the-snapped-to-element-for-jquery-ui-draggable-elements/

Comment: I've read through that post a few times and am still confused as to how I can dynamically resize the image based on which container it is snapped to. I was able to put something together like this: http://jsfiddle.net/W8yaz/551/ but this keeps the image the same size when it is dragged out (I need to revert back to 100x100) and I can only apply one size change.

Comment: I saw your progress and it looks you are on the right direction. Here is an idea after snap:
- copy snapped image as a var
- remove from DOM the image
- add it inside the element you are snapping to it
- allow it to resize automatically via CSS 100% height and width

Comment: I got the image resize to work! - http://jsfiddle.net/W8yaz/556/ Unfortunately, it's not working with the markup I have listed above. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with all your code properly arranged? I tried to copy paste the code the the results were difficult to understand :)