# jQuery UI Snappable Not Returning only Inner Snaps with SnapMode Set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

When I set up draggable object to Snap to a span (doing inner-snaps only) I am seeing it often returning the adjacent snaps, despite clearly being outside of them.  Notice the [SnapMode](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-snapMode), as it is the most important part:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    snap: ".snap",
    snapMode: "inner",
    stop: function(event, ui) { 
        /* Get the possible snap targets: */
        var snapped = $(this).data('draggable').snapElements;

        /* Pull out only the snap targets that are "snapping": */
        var snappedTo = $.map(snapped, function(element) {
            return element.snapping ? element.item : null;
        });

        /* Display the results: */
        var result= '';
        $.each(snappedTo, function(idx, item) {
            result += $(item).text() + ", ";
        });

        $("#results").html("Snapped to: " + (result === '' ? "Nothing!" : result));
    }
});
```

This is originally based upon this question:[How to find out about the "snapped to" element for jQuery UI draggable elements on snap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177867/how-to-find-out-about-the-snapped-to-element-for-jquery-ui-draggable-elements)

**I need the "snappable" areas to be next to each other per the design I'm trying to build towards, like so:**
[image: drag and drop UI example]

My jsFiddle demonstrating this issue is here: http://jsfiddle.net/myingling/dx54dapr/1/

(Try snapping to Snap 2 and you'll see it SAYS it's snapping to BOTH Snap 1 AND Snap 2!)

Comment: I think you need to put some space between the two snap areas

Comment: Why, if I'm using `snapMode: "inner"`?  Shouldn't that detect only objects inside the dropped area?

Answer (score 0):

Snap mode check whether the element should snap to other elements. `snapMode` Determines which edges of snap elements the draggable will snap to. So you need to put some gap between boxes and you can also use `snapTolerance`.

```js
$(".draggable").draggable({
    snap: ".snap",
    snapMode: "inner",
    stop: function(event, ui) { 
        /* Get the possible snap targets: */
        var snapped = $(this).data('ui-draggable').snapElements;
       
        /* Pull out only the snap targets that are "snapping": */
        var snappedTo = $.map(snapped, function(element) {
            return element.snapping ? element.item : null;
        });
       
        /* Display the results: */
        var result= '';
        $.each(snappedTo, function(idx, item) {
            result += $(item).text() + ", ";
        });
        
        $("#results").html("Snapped to: " + (result === '' ? "Nothing!" : result));
    }
});
```

```css
.draggable { 
    width: 90px; 
    height: 80px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    font-size: .9em; 
}

.snap { 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-xNjb53/rY+WmG+4L6tTl9m6PpqknWZvRt0rO1SRnJzw="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.7/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="snap-one" class="snap ui-widget-header">Snap 1</div>
<div id="snap-two" class="snap ui-widget-header">Snap 2</div>

<div class="demo">
    <br clear="both" />
    
    <div id="draggable" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
        <p>Oh Snap!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: On the page I'm trying to design I'm creating many rows of these elements, so putting large margins between them doesn't work.  Mocks of what my real-world use case is can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142843/css-position-absolute-on-one-axis-only-to-prevent-collision-overlap-without-wa

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot showing the issue even better.  If spacing had worked, the original question/answer that I linked would have sufficed.  Sorry for my originally poor explanation.